# Adding hours to asp:boundfield Date control

Tags: asp.net

I need to fix some legacy ASP.NET code I inherited (ASP.NET 2.0) that uses the `<asp:BoundField>` to bind a `DateTime` to a field, like this;

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Date" 
 DataFormatString="{0:T}" HeaderText="Time" HtmlEncode="False"
 SortExpression="Date" 
/>
```

The problem is that I need to add hours to the date output, since it is stored in UTC.

It gets its data from a really wonky `<asp:SqlDataSource>` - I'll add here, I don't know SQL very well, and I know these controls even less...

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="storeSessions" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MSSQL %>"
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MSSQL.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Employees.FirstName, Employees.LastName, Logins.Date, Locations.Name AS Site FROM Logins INNER JOIN Employees ON Logins.Employee = Employees.Id INNER JOIN Locations ON Logins.Location = Locations.Id WHERE (Logins.Date BETWEEN @Date AND @Date + ' 23:59:59:997') AND (Logins.Location = @Site)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="insertBirthdayPicker" Name="Date" PropertyName="SelectedDate" DefaultValue="8/1/2006" />
            <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="Site" SessionField="Site" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Is there any way to add the hours?

Comment: Checking this : http://forums.asp.net/t/1480634.aspx?adding+x+number+of+days+to+a+date+field+in+a+gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change your sql-query as follows:

```
    SELECT Employees.FirstName, 
           Employees.LastName, 
           DATEADD(hour, -6, Logins.Date) as Date, --here you add (-6) to your datetime
           Locations.Name AS Site 
      FROM Logins 
INNER JOIN Employees 
        ON Logins.Employee = Employees.Id 
INNER JOIN Locations 
        ON Logins.Location = Locations.Id 
     WHERE (Logins.Date BETWEEN @Date AND @Date + ' 23:59:59:997') 
       AND (Logins.Location = @Site)
```

Comment: Oh my god, this is perfect! Thank you so much!